# How do you do zero's bore glitch to the bunker

Tags: borderlands-2

Hey I've recently been farming the bunker for drops and exp and I've done the glitch accidentally three times.

I really want too know how to do it more often to shorten the time we are fighting to improve the chances of the rare drops and to level faster so I can complete the missions I'm on.

I have gotten the bitc# on my third time farming him so I'm really in it for the levels about now so any tips on how to successfully pull of the bore glitch would really help

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can use any weapon to do the glitch, just aim for either spot where the upper turrets spawn, with little practise you can do it everytime.

Answer (score 1):

This video suggests that a shotgun to the lower hull does the trick:

Some forum posts suggest shooting the eye crit areas just before the turrets deploy as well.

As of yet I am not sure if it can be performed time after time.

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot I have now completed the glitch 5 times in a row.

Comment: Is that just any shotgun or a super-explodey awesomesauce shotgun of eternal doom? I mean, how easy is it to do this glitch if you don't already have amazing legendary weapons?

Comment: @Alex By the looks of it, the shotgun is not Torgue or that **Flakker** you must be talking about. You do need **The Bee**, though, but it is one of the easiestly farmable :)

Answer (score 0):

Shoot him a bit right from the spot where he spawns his (from his perspective right) left turret. B0re-ing bunker is one of the easiest things in the game, as it can be performed 100% of the times with even lower-level shit white-tier weapons :^) Its too easy. Dont make a big deal out of it